# intermittent power up failure after shut down

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, diagnostic

My desktop with ASUS P5L-MX motherboard does not immediately want to boot up whenever it is completely shut down. When the switch is pressed there are no visible lights, fan motion or anything. It happens every time. Then if I re-seat the power cable, and sometimes remove USB devices, then try again it suddenly powers up again. Doing a reboot without completely shutting down is no problem at all. Is this the power supply or motherboard? How do I narrow it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could narrow it down by trying another power supply in the computer, or putting your current power supply on a tester.  It is also possible to test your PSU with a regular multi-meter, but it's a bit involved.  I'll edit my question to include instructions how if you want them.  At the very least, going in this direction would help you to either identify the PSU as the culprit, or eliminate it as a suspect... and that would be narrowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem every time I shut down my desktop. When I pressed power on button, nothing happened but the motherboard LED was on, sometimes it worked fine.

I also had the ASUS motherboard P5G41T-M LX3. When I had it checked by a professional the **problem was found to be the motherboard** and I had to replace it. They also ruled out the PSU.

It seems this problem occurs on ASUS motherboards. Mine was only Seven months old. I already bought a new motherboard from MSI and it works perfect now.